# how to call (invoke) onChildClick method of expandable listview?

Tags: android, imageview, invoke, expandablelistview, onclicklistener

I'm working on expandable list view. I've set onClickHandler on imageview of the child row, because inline clicklistners not working in this case. But I need int groupPosition and childPosition for some processing in my program. And these are available from OnChildClick().

The problem is I need OnclickHandler and OnChildClick() (for groupPosition and ChildPosition) both. Is there anyway to get these two values? can we call (invoke) OnChildClick method manually?

```
public class ExpList extends ExpandableListActivity
  {
       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
         @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
          {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() 
            {
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) 
                {
                     // some calculations here....
                     return false;
                }
            });
  }


public void onClickHandler (View v) 
 {
     switch (v.getId()) {
         case R.id.imgcall:     

            //Here I need groupPosition and ChildPosition....

                 my_function();
                 break;        

         case R.id.img_call_icon:

                 // some code here......                    
                break;
            }               
     }
 }
```

My child_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_call_type"

        android:layout_width="40px"
        android:layout_height="40px"/>

         <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/space"                   
         android:layout_width="10px"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/name"         
             android:textSize="14px"             
             android:layout_width="115px"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/number"
             android:textSize="14px"             
             android:layout_width="115px"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/date"         
             android:textSize="14px"          
             android:layout_width="115px"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

        <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/time"
             android:textSize="14px"         
             android:layout_width="115px"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />        

    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



<!-- on this imageview i put OnClickHandler -->    

            <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/img_call_icon"

        android:layout_width="40px"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClickHandler"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621070/get-context-of-popupmenu-like-contextmenu

Answer (score -1):

You can get Button Clicks on your child Click listner.
In Short just copy paste your switch case statement of 'onClickHandler' to 'onChildClick'.

So, your code will be,

```
public class ExpList extends ExpandableListActivity
  {
       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
         @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
      {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() 
        {
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) 
            {
                 switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.imgcall:     

        //Here I need groupPosition and ChildPosition....

             my_function();
             break;        

     case R.id.img_call_icon:

             // some code here......                    
            break;
        }               
     }
            }
        });
  }
```

Don't forget to mark this as Answer if its helpful to you..